# Is This a Single Event UDP Socket?

Tags: python, sockets, udp

Apologies in advance for I am very new to socket programming, and what little experience I have is within frameworks like Tornado and Flask.

This code, apparently, emits [UDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol), but I'm not sure where to pick it up, or where it would be picked up.

```
"""
Simple, asynchronous, nonblocking UDP emitter for Cube metrics.
"""

import json
import socket
from datetime import datetime

def emit(event_type="always", event_data={},
                destination='127.0.0.1', port=1180, **kwargs):
    event = dict(type=event_type, data=event_data)
    # event["time"] = kwargs.get("time", datetime.utcnow().isoformat())
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, 0)
    s.connect((destination, port))
    s.send(json.dumps(event))
    s.close()

emit()
```

Searched the rest of the accompanying library for the destination: 127.0.0.1 and port: 1180, with no results.

Web browser can't connect to `127.0.0.1:1180` (I'm on OS X), although a Flask app is fine at `127.0.0.1:5000`.

Found the [BinaryTides tutorial on UDP sockets](http://www.binarytides.com/programming-udp-sockets-in-python/), but they seem to use `while` statements.

Is this "emitter" just a single event, and if so, where, when and how can I see it's output?

Comment: You need to have _something_ listening on port 1180, or anything you send there just goes nowhere. (And a web browser doesn't do UDP, it does TCP, so a web browser being able to connect to `127.0.0.1:1180` would just tell you there's a TCP server there, not a UDP server.)

Comment: For just testing what's going on, you can use Netcat; the exact details depend on whether you've got BSD, GNU, or Hobbit Netcat (OS X comes with BSD by default), but something like `nc -ukl 1180` will listen on UDP port 1180, and print out each message that arrives. That probably won't do you much good, though; presumably you're trying to send this JSON event to some kind of program to do some kind of something with it.

Comment: Or, if you think there _is_ something listening on port 1180, but you don't know what it is, see `man lsof` (or google for help on it) and you can find what process has bound that port.

Comment: Yep, it's a single event - your code only calls `send` once (via `emit`). Too see the output, 1) Take the "Udp server" example code from the tutorial you linked. 2) Change `port = 5000` to `port = 1180`. 3) Run that code in a console. 4) Run your code (from this question) in a second console. 5) You should see `{}` in your first console - that's the server printing out the data sent from your second console.

Comment: @Mac the first, "simplest form" example?

Comment: @Mac Oh yes. This first, simple example did the trick. And when I run the cod that feeds "emit" WOW, is it emitting! Now off to `man lsof` and see what process is bound to port `1180`

Comment: @MikeiLL: I'm not sure why you'd bother with `lsof`. If you've successfully tested it as I described (and it seems you have), then you already know what's on port 1180 - it's the server you ran in step 3.

Comment: @Mac. Ha. That actually made me laugh. I'm trying to figure out what, is anything, the original library is doing with this `emit` method. It runs a few processes, but `lsof -U` doesn't produce anything on `1180` - which, I guess is to be expected since that port doesn't exist in the code. Maybe it's there for testing purposes, but what it feeds to the server you directed me toward looks pretty hard to actually make any use of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above method is called via a loop, so on each pass it does generate a single `.json` object.

It was designed to send to a [Cube Server](http://square.github.io/cube/).